# In Tiny Monsters for iOS, what level is required for monster evolution?

Tags: tiny-monsters

In the game tiny monsters for iPhone, you feed monsters to increase their level.  After advancing a certain number of levels the monster needs to "evolve" before further leveling is possible.  This is accomplished by pressing the "tuck in" button for that monster, after you have purchased and built the "Dream Room", and is sometimes referred to as "hibernation".

> After observing that monsters evolved during a prolonged deep sleep, Phineas Alexander suggested the explorers build a specialized hibernation center known as the Dream Room. Carved into an enormous tree, the building ensures the creatures have the most relaxing and peaceful sleeping situation possible while simultaneously protecting them during hibernation.

So, what are the level requirements for the baby to teen and teen to adult evolutions?  For example, how many levels does an earth monster have to reach before it can hibernate in the dream room?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.gameteep.net/tiny-monsters/beginners-guide/):

> You can tuck in your Tiny Monsters monsters at level 5 and level 8. There is a wait time for the tuck in so sit tight.

This is consistent with my experience, all monsters are ready to be "tucked in" for hibernation at the same levels.

Answer (score -1):

Wait till level 5, when they evolve.

Comment: Can you elaborate?